# Restrict access to MMC snap-ins using groups with GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I'm on Windows Server 2012 R2.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I'm trying to give certain users access to certain snap-ins of MMC by adding them to specific groups which grant them access to a certain snap-in.

I've created a GPO object and linked it in my `Users` folder (not the default one).

That GPO object disabled all the snap-ins by enabling:

```
Restrict users to the explicitly permitted list of snap-ins.
```

This works fine. Now I'm trying to create some groups, for example:

- MMC_ADUC_ACCESS -> Should grant access to Active Directory Users and Computers.
- MMC_DHCP_ACCESS -> Should grant access to the DHCP snap-in.

---

**What's going wrong**

So, I've created the groups and created a GPO object for both of them respectively. But it refuses to overwrite the one that disables all of the snap-ins. (All the snap-ins are on the "Not configured" setting).

---

**What I've tried**

I've set the scope of the object to the respective group, in the delegation settings I've configured it so that it should only apply to the group. Not to anything else.

---

My question: Why isn't the one GPO overwriting the other?

I'm also open to any other suggestions to get this to work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you set the precedence of the GPO that disables all snapins to be lower than the other two?

Comment: The one that disables all the snapins is linked in the `Users` OU. The other one just applies to the group, where should I link it? Because it doesn't show up in the inheritance tab.

Comment: Link it in a hierarchy where the user accounts are located. Linking a GPO to an OU with groups doesn't do anything.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I would think that linking it to the hierachy where the user accounts are would apply it to all of the users? Did it not do that because I changed the scope to only apply it to the group? Anyway, you can add it as an answer and I'll accept it..

Comment: You link it to the OU or Container where the user accounts are. You filter it on your group so that it only applies to members of that group.